# React - show loading message before fetched data is rendered

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a react app that communicating with the server to query data from database. I want to display a loading message when the app is fetching data. Here's the code snippet:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this); 

        this.state = {
            isLoading: false, 
            data: [], 
            content: ''
        }
    }

    clickHandler() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true }); 
        fetch('url_1')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }, () => {
            this.getContentByData() // loading message vanished before content is displayed
          }))
          .then(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false }));
    }

    getContentByData() {
        fetch(`url_2?data=${this.state.data}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(content => this.setState({ content: content }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.isLoading ? <h1>loading</h1>: null}
                <h6>{this.state.content}</h6>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.clickHandler}>Click Me!</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

The loading message disappeared before content is displayed. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have the render ready. So, all you need to do is do `this.setState({ isLoading: true })` in `clickHandler` and upon receiving data, revert it back to false

Answer (score 3):

You could change your `render` method to be something like this:

```
render() {
    let content = <Loader />;
    if (!this.state.isLoading && this.state.content) {
       content = (
           <h6>{this.state.content}</h6>
           <button type="button" onClick={this.clickHandler}>Click Me!</button>
       )
    }
        return (
        <div>
            {content}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Where `Loader` is your loader component. Of course it can also be the h1 title or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need to off your loading at getContentByData() like below.

```
 getContentByData() {
        fetch(`url_2?data=${this.state.data}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(content => this.setState({ content: content, isLoading : false }))
    }
```

do not forget to remove isLoading=false in clickHandler() method.

Answer (score 0):

`isLoading` will be set to false before the fetch inside `getContentByData` is complete, since it's not part of the promise chain in `clickHandler`.

You could instead set `isLoading` to false when the fetch in `getContentByData` is complete.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    data: [],
    content: ""
  };

  clickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    fetch("url_1")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }, this.getContentByData));
  };

  getContentByData = () => {
    fetch(`url_2?data=${this.state.data}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(content => this.setState({ isLoading: false, content }));
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even better you can render something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
  <div>
      {this.state.isLoading && !this.state.content && <Loader />}
      {!this.state.isLoading && this.state.content && (
      <Fragment>
        <h6>{this.state.content}</h6>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.clickHandler}>Click Me!</button>}
      </Fragment>)
  </div>
)
}
```